# Opening Attachments

Tags: email

I am presently unable to open attachments via email when accessed with Tor.

I have have tried 2x different email providers with the same result, whereby the attachment is loaded but cannot be opened.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you trying to open it in the browser itself? If so, try downloading the attachment first, and then open it.

Comment: Hi K, I am trying to open the attachments via the browser, and have downloaded the attachments, but once downloaded I am unable to open the documents, but I can open the attachments via Internet Explorer. Only through Tor I am experience this problem, I am using Windows 10 if that could cause any difficulties. Thanks.

Comment: Once you've downloaded and saved the attachments to your desktop, there shouldn't be any problem opening them. Do you have NoScript enabled? This doesn't seem like a Tor Browser issue really